# Outlook event: On change 'From Address'

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

Does any one know if it is possible to hook into the event when a user changes the 'From' address drop-down in Outlook 2016:

[image]

I've gotten as far as testing out some VBA macros for events `Application.ItemLoad` and `Application.ItemSend` etc. but I was hoping there was more events I could hook into.

Answer (score 4):

The [PropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866739.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the MailItem class is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, Subject) of an instance is changed. Be aware, you may not get the event fired as soon as you change the value in the UI. Outlook may not fire events until the focus is moved to another field or the item is saved.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness - here is the full code I have implemented to capture the event I am interested in.

```
Dim WithEvents myInspector As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Set myInspector = Application.Inspectors

End Sub

Private Sub myInspector_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)

    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
        Set myMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub myMailItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)

    ' Properties we are interested in: "SendUsingAccount" / "SentOnBehalfOfName"
    ' Both get fired when the 'From' field is changed/re-selected
    ' So we are only going to trigger on one event or we will call the code twice
    If Name = "SentOnBehalfOfName" Then
        MsgBox myMailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When the message sender is changed, the following sequence of the `MailItem.PropertyChange` event will fire:

```
PropertyChange ("SendUsingAccount")
PropertyChange ("SentOnBehalfOfName")
```

You can see the live events in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - open the new item, click Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab - OutlookSpy will log the events as they are raised.